# How to have widgets outside the app using flutter and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dart, flutter

I am trying to build a flutter container that can be outside the app like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrwXD.jpg

I figured out that this was impossible to make this just by using flutter. So I tried to use flutter and native components for making this widget. I figured out how to make platform channels. But I didn't know how to make the container widget visible even outside the app. I prefer using kotlin more than java. If there are any good tutorials on this please tell me. But I would greatly appreciate it if you answer my question and edit my full code.

**Code:**

Flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

  class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  static const platform = const MethodChannel('flutter.rortega.com.channel');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container ();
  }
  Future<Null> _showNativeView() async {}

}
```

Kotlin:

```
package com.example.swipe

import android.os.Bundle

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity() : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "flutter.rortega.com.channel"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

        MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

        }
    }
}
```